# Using flowVar in a connector configuration?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I'm trying to use a flowVar in a connector configuration setting as follows:

[image: Work Market connector configuration]

As you can see in the below image, I'm doing a lookup in the Transform Message step that sets a flowVar via a subflow database request.  The logger step is showing me that the flowVar is indeed present and contains the value I expect in `configuration[0].wmApiKey`, but I keep getting errors from the Work Market connector's attempt to call the Work Market API that the Access Token is not correct.  When I just replace the Configuration Access Token value with the static token string, it works.  I cannot figure out why the flowVar approach fails.

[image: Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use flowVars or any runtime data at the configuration level as the connector configurations are initialised at startup. If the connector is using out of the box oauth support from devkit though, then those same attributes can be configured on the operation itself within the flow instead of the conifg.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure with this connector. But i have use sessionVars with Http connector for host and authorization, it works well.

Answer (score -2):

Even if you were able to use sessionVars for configuration initialization, it is not the right thing to do. Connector configuration should always be static